# postgres || aggregation taking time

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization, indexing

below query is taking 5-6 seconds to execute. Is there any way it can be improved? There are approx 1.9 Million records in the table and qualifying records are 0.9 Million

**Query:**

```
Select startdate,  perosntypecode,  verificationstatuscode, activitynumber, enddate, activityname,  COUNT(*)
from personmoderation
where  startdatetimegmt >= '2018-06-12T10:00:56'
and embarkdate between (SELECT p.startdate FROM personmoderation AS p 
                     WHERE p.startdatetimegmt >= '2018-06-12T10:00:56' 
                     ORDER BY p.startdatetimegmt ASC LIMIT 1
                   ) 
                and (SELECT p.startdate FROM personmoderation AS p
                     WHERE p.startdatetimegmt >= '2018-06-12T10:00:56' 
                     ORDER BY p.startdatetimegmt ASC LIMIT 1
                   ) + interval '100 days' 
group by startdate,  perosntypecode,  verificationstatuscode, activitynumber, enddate, activityname
```

**Index:**

```
create
    index ix1 on
    personmoderation
        using btree(
        startdatetimegmt,
        startdate,
        persontypecode,
        verificationstatuscode,
        activitynumber,
        enddate,
        activityname
);
```

Note: The subquery used in the where clause is taking 3-4 milliseconds.

Comment: Now that is a weird query. Why `BETWEEN` when both ends of the interval are identical? `=` would make more sense. A second index on `embarkdate` *might* help. Remove all but the first column from the existing index. Put the subquery in a `WITH` clause. And, most of all: always include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output with such questions.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  In fact, I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.  The logic doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I don't know if the optimizer i able to catch, that your probably expensive `SELECT p.startdate ... ORDER BY p.startdatetimegmt ASC LIMIT 1` is equivalent to a possibly much cheaper `SELECT min(p.startdate) ...`.